# Difference of collection of point charges and charge distribution

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

In electromagnetism, what is the difference between 'collection of point charges' and 'charge distributions'?

Answer (score 1):

A "collection of [finite-sized, non-infinitesimal] point charges" is a type of "charge distribution".

A "continuous distribution of charge [generally with varying density]" is a type of "charge distribution" that is not a "collection of [finite-sized, non-infinitesimal] point charges."